# How to limit aria2 connections to one server but enable concurrent connections to multiple servers?

Tags: download, aria2

I have a long list urls to download with aria2 from a variety of servers, with some urls from the same server. Here's a snippet of urls.txt:

```
ftp://93.190.206.160/public/c/camaro/%E1%D7%D4%CF%CC%C5%C7%C5%CE%C4%D9/net.ods
ftp://93.190.206.160/public/3/389743v/%E6%CC%C5%DB%CB%C1/%D5%DE%C5%C2%C1/Oktyabr2013.xlsx
ftp://93.190.206.160/public/m/modesti/=))/%E7%E0%E4%E0%F7%E0%203.ods
ftp://93.190.206.160/public/c/camaro/%E1%D7%D4%CF%CC%C5%C7%C5%CE%C4%D9/net.ods
```

I need to be able to limit the number of connections to any individual server to 1, but allow concurrent connections to different servers.

Here's how I would expect to do that:

```
aria2c -iurls.txt -x1 -s1
```

However, at least one of the four urls above fails to download because of too many concurrent connections. I can download all files successfully by adding a -k1 flag, but that will prevent concurrent downloads on other servers.